# Flex SDK vs Flex Framework

Tags: flash, frameworks, sdk

What are the main differences between Flex SDK v4.6 and Flex Framework 3 or 4 (is there a "kit" available for Flex Framework 3 or 4)?
More generally put, what are the main differences between a Flex SDK and a Framework?
I've tried to download Flex Framework as described in this beginner's tutorial [Beginner’s Guide to FlashDevelop – Basix](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-flashdevelop-intro-basix/), but I couldn't find it anywhere on the net (not even on the Adobe site). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK stands for "Software Development Kit". It's basically the thing you need to compile your Flex application.

A framework is something that describes something you use when programming. The Flex Framework provides all the things you can use when programming Flex applications, e.g. the spark or mx components or even MXML.

Of course the Flex SDK can handle all the technologies that are part of the Flex Framework. When the tutorial you mentioned says `"using the Adobe Flex SDK does not mean that you need to use the Adobe Flex framework or MXML"`, it means that it doesn't force you to use anything from the Flex Framework. You could write a simple ActionScript application without using anything from the Framework, but you would still need the SDK to compile it.